# TFS CI build based on code coverage or test pass rate

Tags: build, continuous-integration

I'm trying to setup A CI build in TFS. I would like to have this build determine its success based on the code coverage and/test pass rate but I'm having trouble finding instructions on how to do this.

I have a simple node.js project set up with unit tests but currently if any one test fails, the whole build is marked as failed. How can I configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use powershell script to do this, do a comparison of the control value(fail or pass build) and the code coverage of the build. If it is less than the control value you could **exit with -1** and this would fail the build.

While below blog covers **Code coverage percentage** as the **benchmark** to determine the status of build, success of fail.

[Controlling build result with code coverage percentage (using build vNext)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2015/11/06/controlling-build-result-with-code-coverage-percentage-using-build-vnext/)

And for test pass rate you could use the same method, if any one test fails, the whole build is marked as failed. You could check the option  "**continue on error**"  in related test task under control. This will continue run even the task failed.